# In vi, select lines and copy/paste from different lines

Tags: vi

I know there must be a way to do this. It's somewhat difficult to search this kind of tricks.

What I want is to copy lines from xx to yy and paste them where my cursor is. I know how to yank and paste, but I want to do this without moving my cursor to the lines where I want to copy and get back to the line where I want to paste.

Copy and paste without navigating lines is what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the command-line mode. To yank line 2 to 20

```
:2,20y
```

then just hit p on the current line.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

`:5,6copyN`, where N is the line under which the lines will copied to.

Note that, the line N must exist in your file, i.e. your cursor should be there at least once before you want to do copy/paste.